# How to send a range of cell values to web page text input field

Tags: vba, excel, selenium, web-scraping

I am writing an Excel macro, using Selenium basic, to download data from a web-based tool.

Using Selenium, I need to select 200 cells in a column in Excel and send them to a text box in a webpage.

The following line does this with the single cell A1:

```
driver.FindElementById("batch_requests").SendKeys [A1]
```

How can I send the entire range A1:A200?

Looping through and doing one at a time would be too time-consuming, as there are thousands of data points I need to paste 200 at a time.

Using standard sendkeys in VBA (not Selenium) is not a good solution, because the computer will be in use while the macros run in the background.

**EDIT - Qharr's answer fitted to my needs**

Not the most elegant solution, but it works every time in the situation(s) I will be using it.

```vb
' Copy column A 200 cells at a time into webpage text input field

Dim clipboard As Object
Dim data As String
Dim myRange As Range
Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
' See how many rows of data in column A
numRows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

' Step through column A, 200 cells at a time (until numRows is exceeded)
' and create a range to be copied to clipboard and sent to webpage via Selenium
' 'Batch_Requests' is ID of input field page element to send text to.

For x = 2 To numRows Step 200
    Set myRange = Range("A" & x & ":A" & (x + 200))
    myRange.Copy
    With clipboard
        .GetFromClipboard
        data = .GetText
        driver.FindElementById("batch_requests").SendKeys data
    End With
    
    ' *****************************************************************************
    ' Insert Seleneium code here to manipulate the web page with the data
    ' *****************************************************************************

    ' Clear text input field
    driver.FindElementById("batch_requests").Clear

' Go to next 200 in column A (until none left)
Next x
```

Comment: Can you share an URL?

Comment: Hi Qharr - I can't, sadly, It's behind a paywall and log in.

We can safely assume it's ANY input field in any webpage, it wouldn't change the problem. I can target the input field OK, I just cannot get Sendkeys to recognise and send anything other than a single cell value, or a string.

I'm not even able to find any documentation on Selenium excel VBA. I've gotten as far as I have by finding code and piecing things together somewhat blind sadly :-(

Comment: One option would be to preprocess the Excel sheet and put everything into the format you want. You could write an Excel VBA macro to do this for you. Once it's in the format you want, you run your Selenium script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sendKeys based. Not so bad with selenium in my opinion. I am using the clipboard to generate the text from range to paste

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub PasteInfo()
    Dim d As WebDriver, clipboard As Object, data As String
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const url = "https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester"

    With d
         '.AddArgument "--headless"
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get url
        [A1:A3].Copy

        Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
        With clipboard
            .GetFromClipboard
            data = .GetText
        End With

        .FindElementById("xmlString").SendKeys data
        Stop '<=Delete me later
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @QHarr,

I just adapted the code to fit my script and ran it, it certainly works, thank you very much :-)

Can I just ask: With this code, is it possible for a user - who may be using the computer to do other things while the macros is running in the background - to use the clipboard and overwrite the data from [A1:A3] before  the macro has a chance to paste it?

It looks to me as if the copy is (pretty much) instantly stored into the variable 'data', and so this is very, very unlikely to happen. Is this the case?

Comment: Have you tried `.FindElementById("xmlString").SendKeys [A1:A3]`?

Comment: @GHarr - Your answer worked brilliantly. I tried - quite hard, lol - to break it by copy pasting as it ran, it worked every time.

Thank you very much for your help, I literally wasted about 3 hours not being able to do it before asking here.

Comment: Pleasure. Glad it helped.

Comment: @JeffC, I did and it gets a With block or object not specified error (something worded similarly to that anyway? I can't remember exactly.)

Comment: Hi @Qharr. Turns out it does occasionally fail, at line: data = .GetText :-(

Is there any way to achieve what I'm after without the use of the clipboard? Over the years, clipboard has always seemed to be a very flaky way to achieve the movement of text or data around between apps, unless a human is at the helm to re-do it if it fails.

Comment: Is there a way to create an mcve whereby I can test the failing case? Difficult I expect. I can't think of another way except still using SendKeys and to try  looping an array to send the values to  textbox. This would be less reliable in my opinion.  It is a specific case or is it during repeated pasting during a loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send value by selenium then

1. first go to the web page and inspect the web page and find the name or id of the input field
2. you can send values by the id or name of the input field
3. then go to your vba editor
4. if you aware of vba selenium basic then
   Object_Of_chromedriver.findelmentbyname("NameOfInputField").sendkeys("the value")